# Filtering a table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to filter a table using a JavaScript function, but I'm not sure what the issue is...When clicking the filter link, nothing happens, but it should be filtering the second column ("Platform" column) and only displaying rows with "TEST" in it.

I'm trying to debug it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/7vh5wmsx/

```
function filterTable(input) {
        var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');

        for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            if (tds[1].textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please use ` var filter = input.toUpperCase();`

Comment: `var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");` is wrong, that is `trList` instead of `tr`

Comment: you're calling the function with a string and then trying to read input.value which is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this code**

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```